# Graph API returning empty data

Tags: facebook-graph-api, web-crawler

For a project I'm required to crawl a few Facebook pages using the Graph API (and R). These pages are MonsterEnergy, RedBull and Rockstar. Monster and Rockstar work just fine, but the Graph API is acting up on RedBull. I can only get the posts that were made today.

Example:
https://graph.facebook.com/14226545351/posts?access_token={valid access token}

When going to the "next" URL, only an empty data array is returned.
I have all the permissions enabled on my access token, and I can see all their posts just fine on their page.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook tables dealing with the news feed have been hobbled by design. A call with no limits will only return either the last 30 days of data or 50 posts, whichever is fewer. If a page didn't post for more than 30 days, you can end up with nothing returned.

If you need more posts, rather than paging through them, you're better off passing a `limit` parameter to explicitly request more of them.

Try this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/14226545351/posts?limit=100&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```